# Samba3 PDC with single user profile per OS

Tags: windows-7, samba, domain-controller, profile

I would like to set up a Samba3 PDC on an Ubuntu 10.04 LTS box for Windows XP and Windows 7 Clients. For my application I do not really need the whole profile overhead a normal Windows domain network has. I would much rather like to control one single profile per Operating System, which all users use to login, that is unchangeable by them (mandatory?). It should only be changeable by administrative users for configuration.

For your information I planned to do the software deployment with WPKG and store the users in an OpenLDAP Directory Service.

**How do I best accomplish this single profile configuration with Samba, if even possible, or what is a valid alternative to it?**

I had several problems with access rights and barely got it to work unstablely with Windows XP Clients. Windows 7 Clients are still an enigma, especially because say seem to be a bit stricter with the access rights needed in a profile.

Comment: DO you mean one user per client OS on the Samba Server?  As in, 1 user that everyone running Windows XP logs in as, and 1 user that every Windows 7 client logs in as? What exact errors are you getting with regard to access rights?  What's in the logs?

Comment: Is the Samba server for file sharing via SMB/CFS, or just to do the LDAP and user authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows XP and Windows 7 profiles are not 100% compatible, you will want to have one profile for each OS.

Also, for windows stations not to throw a tantrum, your profile share needs to have appropriate permissions (that includes being writable, even with [mandatory profiles](http://download.microsoft.com/download/3/b/a/3ba6d659-6e39-4cd7-b3a2-9c96482f5353/Managing%20Roaming%20User%20Data%20Deployment%20Guide.doc)), as such, the only way to force a profile on user is to use mandatory profiles.

You need to remember though, that if you want the users to be able to write files to their desktop and My documents, you need to redirect them to network shares.